# How to check if an object contains text from an array in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript

I have an array that contains some names;

```
names:[ 
{"title" : "dog"},
{"title" : "cat"},
{"title" : "bird"}
]
```

I want to find the objects that contains for example `"at"` 
,I tried `.includes()` and `.indexOf` but not worked!
any idea?

Comment: `<something>.names.filter(i => i.title.indexOf("at") > -1);`...?

Comment: Using `includes` on the string is fine, but can you please show us how you tried to iterate the array to look at the strings?

Comment: Do you need to search both key and value if element is one object? or only value?

Comment: Define "not worked", I mean, you're not looking for a string, you're looking for a partial string match, so ... you'd need `filter` if you want the results, or any of several libraries' versions of `any` etc.

Comment: @briosheje thanks it worked

Comment: @MojtabaMoshfeghifar I guess you can accept Rainer's answer below, using a regex is even slightly better.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try a simple filter.

```
names = [ 
  {"title" : "dog"},
  {"title" : "cat"},
  {"title" : "bird"},
  {"title" : "rats"}
];
namesWithAt = names.filter((obj) => {return obj.title.match(/.*at.*/);});
```

i used regexp since it offers more complex search features( not in my example ofc )